# modrewrite rule to trick apache into believing a PHP is a JS one

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In one of my external JS files, there's some code that could be written much easier if a php variable could be got from the URL. For that reason, I tried to edit the .htaccess file so that header.php could be read as header.js.

```
# Header.php into header.js
RewriteRule ^js/header.php$ js/header.js
```

But, when I put the following in the head of my document, Chrome's javascript console says it found a 404 error and the file could not be loaded.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/header.js?url=<?php echo $url; ?>"></script>
```

I thought that for a second, it was because of the GET variable that was being passed along
in the query string. But, then when I viewed the header.js file in a browser found [here](http://sportannica.com/js/header.js), it shows a 404 error... leaving me to believe that the modrewrite rule isn't working correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, or why you think a rewrite rule is the solution.

Comment: Having the JS file really be a PHP file makes it much more flexible

Comment: Yes. So where does mod_rewrite come in?

Comment: I've heard that some browsers wont let a file with an extension other than .js be loaded for javascript. Is that not true?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it written, the RewriteRule is expecting the URL `/js/header.php` to be called from the browser and it is going to rewrite that to `/js/header.js`. This is the opposite of what you want. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^js/header.js$ /js/header.php [L]
```

Note that I also added a slash at the start of the rewritten path - this is dependent on context, but you'll probably need it.

Comment: Actually, upon further scrutiny, this modrewrite rule doesn't indeed work.